# MS-Access: Replace values in column based on mapping list

Tags: ms-access

I got a column with 27 thousand entries. I want to replace all occurences of "a" with "a_new", all occurences of "b" with "b_whatever". And so on. I got more than 1200 of these mappings. Can I somehow put my mappings into a list and feed it to MS-Access so that it replaces the values in a specific column?

Comment: Yes you can, put your mappings in a new table and then look into SQL-Syntax

Answer (score 2):

Create new table with mapping - `[OldValue]` and `[NewValue]` columns, then join this table with your existing table by `[OldValue]` column and update by value from '[NewValue]`